# Importing an externally defined function to pytorch Dataset

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I have the following problem. I am defining a dataset class for my pytorch dataloader. In the class, I would like to use an externally defined function in the `__getitem__` method.

Here is the example of what I mean

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import pandas as pd

def readOneElement(df, idx):
   # some fancy code which returns one element with index i based on full data set df (pandas)
   ...
 


# And here the Dataset class 
class ModelDataset(Dataset):

def __init__(self, dataPath, transform = None):

     def listUniqueExamples(self, df):
         listExamples = df[['criterionId', 'adGroupId', 'campaignId', 'accountId']].drop_duplicates().reset_index();
         return listExamples 
     
     self.transform = transform

     # Load data
     df = pd.read_csv(dataPath + '/trainData.csv')

     # Transform constants to self
     self.df = df
     self.listExamples = listUniqueExamples(self, self.df)
     self.length = len(self.listExamples)

def __len__(self):
     return self.length

def __getitem__(self, idx):
     # Create one example data
     sample = readOneElement(df = self.df, idx = idx) # !!!

     return sample
```

The line marked with #!!! will not work, because the function was defined outside this Dataset object. I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 
in 
----> 1 data[20]

in __getitem__(self, idx)
     31     def __getitem__(self, idx):
     32          # Create one example data
---> 33          sample = readOneElement(df = self.df, idx = idx)

NameError: name 'readOneElement' is not defined
```

If I would have defined this function inside the Dataset object (as I have done for the `listUniqueExamples` function) then it would have worked. However, in this exact case I want this function to be external.

Is there any way to import external functions to the Dataset class in pytorch?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please narrow the code down to the essentials. This seems to be about fundamentals about Python functions and classes, and not about PyTorch.

Comment: What kind of error did you get, since code above expected to work well?

Comment: Thank you for your questions, I have edited the question respectively and added the error message I get @trsvchn

Comment: You have a typo: defined `readOneElement`  vs `readOneExample` in `__getitem__`?

Comment: I see that you are using `jupyter` did you try to `Restart and Run all` to update the stack? It may happen that previously defined funcs with older names are still alive

Comment: @gdol Great! Happy Pytorching!

Comment: How did you see it was on Jupyter ?

Comment: @White Traceback is formatted in typical `jupyter` style.